# My program endpoint key specified key does not exists this error

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-endpoints

```
@app.route('/create_model', methods=['POST'])
def create_model():
    try:
        user_id = request.form.get('user_id')
        project_id = request.form.get('project_id')
        target_column = request.form.get('target_column')


        # Fetch the dataset from the database
        dataset = Upload.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id, project_id=project_id).first()

        if not dataset:
            return {"error": "Dataset not found"}, 404


        # Check if a model already exists
        model_details = ModelDetails.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id, project_id=project_id).first()

        if not model_details:
            # Create a new record if no existing model found
            model_details = ModelDetails(user_id=user_id, project_id=project_id, model_name="LinearRegression",
                                         status="training",created_at = datetime.utcnow())
            db.session.add(model_details)
        else:
            # Update the existing record
            model_details.status = "training"
            model_details.created_at = datetime.utcnow()

        db.session.commit()

        # Fetch the dataset file from S3
        bucket_name = 'yungsen-test-bucket'
        file_key = 'datasets/' + dataset.filename
        file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
        try:
            mse,r2,model = train_model(file_obj,target_column)
        except Exception as e:
            model_details.status = "training Failed"
            db.session.commit()
            return {"error": f"An error occurred while training model: {str(e)}"}, 500

        # Save the model to S3
        model_filename = f"{user_id}_{project_id}_model.joblib"
        s3_model_path = 'models/' + model_filename  # S3 path
        joblib.dump(model, model_filename)
        s3.upload_file(model_filename, bucket_name, 'models/' + model_filename)

        # Update the model details record with the metrics and status "training completed"
        model_details.accuracy = r2
        model_details.mse = mse
        model_details.precision = None  # Update with actual value if classification problem
        model_details.f1_score = None  # Update with actual value if classification problem
        model_details.status = "training completed"
        model_details.s3_model_path = s3_model_path
        model_details.created_at = datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()


        return {"message": "Model training completed", "mse": mse, "r2_score": r2}, 200
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": f"An error occurred: {str(e)}"}, 500
```

Above program create model endpoint shows error.
The endpoint program given below

```
import requests

# URL of the endpoint
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_model'  # Replace this with the actual URL of your endpoint

# Sample form data
form_data = {
    'user_id': 'AnandX1',
    'project_id': 'Sample1',
    'target_column': 'Price'
}

try:
    # Sending a POST request to the endpoint with form data
    response = requests.post(url, data=form_data)

    # Check the response status code
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Request was successful, print the response message and data
        data = response.json()
        print("Success:", data['message'])
        print("Mean Squared Error (MSE):", data['mse'])
        print("R2 Score:", data['r2_score'])
    elif response.status_code == 500:
        # Server error occurred, print the error message
        print("Server Error:", response.json()['error'])
    else:
        # Unexpected response status code, print the response content
        print("Unexpected Response:", response.status_code, response.content)
        

except Exception as e:
    # An exception occurred during the request, print the error message
    print("Error:", str(e))
```

After check this endpoint threw error:

> Server Error: An error occurred: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not
> exist.

The endpoint should be run. What is the  problem in this endpoint?